# Select multiple min values from subset of values

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am creating an access system. The access system is based on that a user can be a member of more than one group, the domain is where the user ask for access. For example an user can be a member of two groups, both these groups can have access to the domain and the user can be a member of the domain. I want the lowest access right to be the valid one, say you get added to a group that have lower right in that domain that right should precede the other right.

The problem is that i want to select each domain and get all the access rights for each domain. 
So the problem is to select a min value from multiple subset. Got an idea to how to do this ?

So i have tried :

```
SELECT r.* FROM `domain` as d 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT domain, min(`update`) FROM `right` 
    ) r ON d.name = r.domain;
```

*This gives me the result :*

domain          min(`update`)

Another test    true

*What i want is :*

domain          min(`update`)

Another test    true

Some Name       true

Sql fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/841183

Export of the sql table with test values:

```
CREATE TABLE `domain` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `displayName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `domain`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`name`);

CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `groups`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  ADD KEY `groups_created_by_foreign` (`created_by`);


CREATE TABLE `right` (
  `domain` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `update` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `create` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `modify` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `execute` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `right`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`domain`,`group`),
  ADD KEY `right_group_foreign` (`group`),
  ADD KEY `right_created_by_foreign` (`created_by`);


INSERT INTO `domain` (`name`, `displayName`, `description`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
('Another test', 'Another test', NULL, '2016-08-22 12:05:06', '2016-08-22 12:05:06'),
('Some Name', 'Some Name', NULL, '2016-08-19 03:57:00', '2016-08-19 03:57:00');


INSERT INTO `groups` (`name`, `created_by`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
('groupTest', NULL, '2016-08-22 12:06:48', '2016-08-22 12:06:48'),
('testGroup', NULL, '2016-08-19 03:56:35', '2016-08-19 03:56:35');


INSERT INTO `right` (`domain`, `group`, `read`, `update`, `create`, `delete`, `modify`, `execute`, `created_by`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
('Another test', 'groupTest', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '2016-08-22 12:07:02', '2016-08-22 12:07:02'),
('Another test', 'TestGroup', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '2016-08-22 12:06:04', '2016-08-22 12:06:04'),
('Some Name', 'TestGroup', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '2016-08-19 03:57:05', '2016-08-19 03:57:05');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `group by` clause to get the minimum values by groups. By groups here I mean the domains:

```
select d.name, min(`update`) as min_update_right
from domain d
inner join `right` r on d.name = r.domain
group by d.name
```

If you want additional fields from the domain table to be present in the select list, then you need to add those fields to the group by list as well.

However, I would consider using a bitmap (or in MySQL the `set` data type) instead of multiple fields to store access rights. Simple bitwise operations could give you the overall access right to a domain.